# Gerrit change status not updated after a delete action

Tags: gerrit

Gerrit version 3.2.3 and I have some change deleted.

But it still show in my Incoming dashboard with a status ‘--’.
And I click into the change then an error comes out

```
/a/changes/xxx/ Not found
```

In my view status should be updated when I make the 'delete' action.

Make nonsense here. Any idea is appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by reindex offline.